# How to access formdata response in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, response, multipartform-data

**Component.ts**

```
 upload() {
      var formData: any = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', this.name);
      this.http.post('/temp/upload', formData,{responseType: 'text' })
        .subscribe((response) => {
             console.log('response received is ', response);
             if(response.code==400){
    alert("Upload success")
    }
    else{
    alert("Upload failed")
    }

      });}
```

**server.js**

```
 //upload
    router.post('/upload){
    if(!error){
       res.send({
             code: 400,
             success: "Upload success"
              });
    else{
    res.send({
    code:200
    }}
    }
```

**The above upload function returns code:400 on success, The problem is I'm able to access "Property 'code' does not exist on type 'string'"**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: a 400 code will never end up in the subscribe - this is an error code and should be caught as an error. Why a 400 for a success in the first place?

Comment: What is the outcome from:   console.log('response received is ', response);    ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you get a string. Then you should parse the JSON string via   JSON.parse(response).

An other try :
responseType: 'text'   ->  responseType: 'json'

```
this.http
  .post('/temp/upload', formData, {responseType: 'json'})
  .subscribe((response) => {
      const res = (typeof response === 'string') ? JSON.parse(response): response;
      console.log('response received is ', res);
    },
    (error) => console.error(error)
  );
```